# How to disable debugger warnings about frozen modules when using nbconvert.ExecutePreprocessor in python script?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I am trying to run a python script to run all cells in all notebooks found a directory. It runs fine and I am getting the desired results in the notebook files. However, I want to disable the warnings that are printed to the VSCode cmd terminal when running the script. My code below:

```
import nbformat
from glob import glob
from nbconvert.preprocessors import ExecutePreprocessor

if __name__ == "__main__":

    nb_list = glob("./*.ipynb")

    ep = ExecutePreprocessor()

    for nb in nb_list:
        with open(nb) as f:
            nb_r = nbformat.read(f, as_version=4)
            ep.preprocess(nb_r)
```

The console output:

> 0.00s - Debugger warning: It seems that frozen modules are being used, which may
> 0.00s - make the debugger miss breakpoints. Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off
> 0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules.
> 0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.

- Tried setting **"env": {"PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION":"1"}** in the launch.json file. Didn't change anything.
- Tried setting **"pythonArgs": ["-Xfrozen_modules=off"]** in the launch.json file. Didn't change anything.
- Tried setting **warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', module='ExecutePreprocessor')**. Didn't change anything.
- Tried setting **os.environ['PYTHONWARNINGS'] = ''**. Didn't change anything.
- Tried setting **os.environ['PYDEVD_USE_CYTHON'] = '1'**. Didn't change anything.
- What I haven't tried is setting **PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1**. I don't know where to set this, how to set it, and the implications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out how to "Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation". [Adding a user or system environment variable](https://www.howtogeek.com/787217/how-to-edit-environment-variables-on-windows-10-or-11/) called 'PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION' and setting the value to '1' did the job.

Didn't know this is what it meant (newbie alert).

Answer (score -2):

Please pass -Xfrozen_modules=off 0.00s - to python to disable frozen modules. 0.00s - Note: Debugging will proceed. Set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1 to disable this validation.

Comment: How does repeating the warning in an answer help me?

As mentioned in the question, I tried setting -Xfrozen_modules to off in the launch.json file. But that doesn't seem to work, so I guess that's not it. I don't know how to set PYDEVD_DISABLE_FILE_VALIDATION=1. Is there anything else you can add to your answer to help?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).